# Nifi 1.19 Groovy: Jwts.builder(): jjwt jar missing

Tags: groovy, jwt, apache-nifi

I'm using NiFi 1.19 with Java 11. In ExecuteScript Groovy

```
import io.jsonwebtoken.*

String jwtToken = Jwts.builder()
```

gives me an exeption:  groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: Jwts for ...

I take a closer look at the jar files of the current version and older versions and found

**NiFi 1.12**

nifi-1.12.0\work\nar\framework\nifi-framework-nar-1.12.0.nar-unpacked\NAR-INF\bundled-dependencies

- jackson-core-2.9.10.jar
- jackson-databind-2.9.10.jar
- jackson-annotations-2.9.10.jar
- jjwt-0.6.0.jar

**NiFi 1.19**

nifi-1.19.0\work\nar\framework\nifi-framework-nar-1.19.0.nar-unpacked\NAR-INF\bundled-dependencies

- jackson-core-2.14.0.jar
- jackson-databind-2.14.0.jar
- jackson-annotations-2.14.0.jar

**CONCLUSION**

So it seems that jjwt-x.y.z.jar is missing

- is this the correct assumption or am I wrong?
- which version of jjwt belongs to jackson 2.14? (in the latest download package I found jjwt 0.9.1 with jackson 2.9.6)
- where do I have to copy the jar file? Into the "./extensions" directory and reference it in ExecuteScript Attribute "*Module Directory*"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `jjwt` JAR is a transitive dependency of the framework JAR(s), some of which are themselves dependencies (or transitive dependencies) of the `nifi-scripting-nar`. This means you can't count on any of those transitive dependencies being available for use by `ExecuteScript`, only those that are explicit dependencies in the `nifi-scripting-nar` (and/or `nifi-scripting-processors`) POM.

You can download it yourself and use the `Module Directory` property to point at the JAR(s) or directories containing the JARs. If you're using Groovy you can also use `@Grab` to dynamically download it and add it to the classpath, I have a [blog post](https://funnifi.blogspot.com/2016/05/using-groovy-grab-with-executescript.html) illustrating how to do that.